# How can I map Body Diode datasheet params to simulink N-MOSFET model?

Tags: mosfet, datasheet, body-diode

I would be interested on including the body diode effect of a NMOS transistor into the N-Mosfet that Simspace includes for electronics. However, the parameters that the Body diode in Matlab requires is not completely given in the datasheets.

Let's say that I have the following datasheet , where I can read

[image]

How can I translate these parameters to [the ones shown in of Simulink block](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/physmod/elec/ref/nchannelmosfet.html?searchHighlight=mosfet#bvdhl3l)?

```
  Reverse saturation current
  Built-in voltage
  Ideality factor
  Zero-bias junction capacitance
  Transit time
```

Thanks in advance,

Kind regards!

Comment: Isn't there a spice model provided by the manufacturer, for the MOSFET you got the datasheet from? These models usually consider the body diode effect, and they are easy to use from simulation softwares (although I don't use simulink, so I don't know).

Comment: Hi @dim apparently it is, [link](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd17573q5b.pdf), however it is only for pspice

Comment: Indeed, it looks like an encrypted model that works only for PSpice. Strange. Usually, FET models are in cleartext and can be used with any software. You're unlucky, I guess. Maybe you could make your simulation with another, similar, FET part that has a non-encrypted model.

Comment: Wouldn't be easy to know how to map those datasheet parameters to simulink?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to obtain these parameters. But I'm pretty sure the information given in the datasheet is not enough to deduce them accurately. Which is why I suggested this alternative option. But your question is still legit. I'm just afraid it isn't as easy as you think and you probably won't get the answer you're hoping for (I may be wrong, though).